# {fault.name} - The client_id specified does not have access to the api product

Tags: autodesk-forge

I'm following this tutorial : 
https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/prepare-file-for-viewer/

In previous steps, I get the token, get a token for bucket, create one and upload a file in it.

But, when I try, on the next step, to convert my file to `svg`, I get this message :

`{fault.name} - The client_id specified does not have access to the api product`

In `Postman`, I've do that :

```
POST https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/job

-- Header
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1...

-- Body 
   {
        "input": {
          "urn": "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6ZGV2c3RlZWxidWNrZXQvc2t5c2NwcjEuXXXX"
        },
        "output": {
          "formats": [
            {
              "type": "svf",
              "views": [
                "2d",
                "3d"
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
```

And I do not find any solution in Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [activate your account](http://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/account/?id=activate-subscription).

Comment: Thanks but error have change : Token does not have the privilege for this request.

Comment: you probably created a token without the necessary scope: `data:read` and (`data:write` or `data:create`) https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/job-POST/

Comment: You right! I was using the older token of my previous app. I've create a new one, add the good scopes and here it is. Many thanks !

Answer (score 0):

If you face same issue even after activating your account, another possibility could be-

you might have missed "**Model derivative API**" while creating forge APP.

[image]