# APS BIM360 API: GET modelsets endpoint stopped working

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

I maintain a few apps that call [GET modelsets endpoint](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/mc-modelset-service-v3-get-model-sets-GET/) as a part of the process. They worked as expected for over a year until 11th September, after which they started failing with the following:

```
Status: 503
Response:
{
    "title": "The service is temporarily unavailable.",
    "detail": "The HTTP status code of the response was not expected (403). 
    Status: 403
        Response:
    { 
        "developerMessage": "The client_id specified does not have access to the api product",
        "moreInfo": "https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/developers_guide/error_handling/",
        "errorCode": "AUTH-001"
    }",
    "type": "ServiceUnavailable"
}
```

Since the error has been occurring consistently for almost 4 weeks against multiple projects, I guess it is something bigger than the service being temporarily unavailable.

I was looking for changes in the API or any announcements, double checked APIs enabled in the app settings etc., everything is fine there. What is more, other BIM360 API endpoints respond as expected (e.g. [GET instances](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/checklists-instances-GET/)), which makes the error message even more confusing (i.e. my app has access to the API product itself).

Comment: Has your subscription to BIM360/ACC got expired recently? If yes, please check if the `Document Management` option in the app under the [custom integration](https://tutorials.autodesk.io/#provision-access-in-other-products) is checked.

Comment: In addition, please check the API access at https://aps.autodesk.com/myapps/ and ensure BIM360 API and Autodesk Construction Cloud are selected. If this doesn't help, please consider providing an API call example of [GET modelsets endpoint](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/mc-modelset-service-v3-get-model-sets-GET/) including your `containerId` to `aps (DOT) help (AT) autodesk (DOT) com`. We will help pass it to our engineering team for diagnosis.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly, confirm if you are using the correct credentials of your APS app. Well, that could one reason.
Another reason could be that you have not performed custom integration for your APS app on BIM360/ACC account as explained: **https://tutorials.autodesk.io/**. The connection gives your app permissions to browse through your hub and access about any resource within the given scope.

These similar cases may be of much help, may you take a look: [{fault.name} - The client_id specified does not have access to the api product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50144071/fault-name-the-client-id-specified-does-not-have-access-to-the-api-product)
[the client_id specified does not have access to the api product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72735206/the-client-id-specified-does-not-have-access-to-the-api-product)